# How to cache page in MVC Core, only in Production environment

Tags: .net, caching, asp.net-core-mvc, environment

Is there an easy way to cache an MVC Core page (View) only when in Production environment?  I tried the code below, but the  tag helper doesn't work since the  ending tag must be within the  tag.

```
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <cache expires-after="@TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)">
</environment>
```

Possibly use the enabled attribute for ?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

If you want to cache the entire page, to avoid having a  section as well as one without it (since you still want that content in a Development environment), I would suppose you could put the entire page into a partial view as noted by some.  That would work.  and you would end up with:

```
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <cache expires-after="@TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)">
        @Html.Partial("_PartialViewName")
        *last updated  @DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()
    </cache>
</environment>
<environment names="Development">
    @Html.Partial("_PartialViewName")
</environment>
```

Seem correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the closing to the cache tag. Try adding `</cache>` after your cache tag.

Example:

```cs
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <cache expires-after="@TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)">
        @DateTime.Now
    </cache>
</environment>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap the contents you want cached with a  tag and the contents of the tag will be cached in memory.

```
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <cache expires-after="@TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)">
        @Html.Partial("_PartialViewName")
        *last updated  @DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()
    </cache>
</environment>
```

Comment: I'll mark as answer since this provided the hint to put the contents you want to show, in all environments, in a partial view, then include multiple environment tags, with with <cache> and one without it.